# Save state of click event in hidde/show password function

Tags: javascript

How to save state of click event and when password is displayed the eye button should hide the password?

```
<div class="input-group">
    <input type="password" value="test value" name="password" id="id_password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password">
    <span id="show_password" title="Click here to show/hide password" class="input-group-addon" style="cursor: pointer;"><i id="button-eye" class="fa fa-eye"></i></span>
</div>
```

JS:

```
  var eye_button = document.querySelector('#button-eye');

  eye_button.addEventListener('click', function (event) {
    eye_button_checked = true;
    var password = document.querySelector('#id_password');
    console.log("click");

    if (eye_button_checked) {
      // Show the password
      password.type = 'text';
    } else {
      // Hide the password
      password.type = 'password';
      eye_button_checked = false
    }
    // need to change icon to fa-eye-slash and change password.type to password again

  }, false);
```

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/5apz0khL/1/

Comment: As per your code, every click will reset `eye_button_checked` to `true`. You need to move the declaration and initialization outside your click handler function.

Comment: Here's a fixed version: https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/e8yup0dx/

Comment: @ChrisG please add this as an answer

Comment: This is basically a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500431/what-is-the-scope-of-variables-in-javascript, the rest is just implementation details

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Function-scoped variables are created and destroyed on each call to them, and cannot maintain their state.

You have multiple ways to solve the problem:

- Using global variables (not recommended because of global scope pollution)

  ```
  var eye_button = document.querySelector('#button-eye');
  var eye_button_checked = false
  eye_button.addEventListener('click', function (event) {
      var password = document.querySelector('#id_password');
      console.log("click");

      //Invert the variable
      eye_button_checked=!eye_button_checked

      password.type = eye_button_checked ? 'text' : 'password';
      // need to change icon to fa-eye-slash and change password.type to password again

  }, false);
  ```
- Or, use a block-scoped variable, and a block that encapsulates it (prevents from being accessed outside):

  ```
  var eye_button = document.querySelector('#button-eye');
  {
      let eye_button_checked = false
      eye_button.addEventListener('click', function (event) {
          var password = document.querySelector('#id_password');
          console.log("click");

          //Invert the variable
          eye_button_checked=!eye_button_checked

          password.type = eye_button_checked ? 'text' : 'password';
          // need to change icon to fa-eye-slash and change password.type to password again

      }, false);
  }
  //eye_button_checked can't be accessed here
  ```
- Alternatively, you can check the `type` of the `password` element, and invert it:

  ```
  var eye_button = document.querySelector('#button-eye');
  eye_button.addEventListener('click', function (event) {
      var password = document.querySelector('#id_password');
      console.log("click");


      password.type = password.type === 'password' ? 'text' : 'password';
      // need to change icon to fa-eye-slash and change password.type to password again

  }, false);
  ```

Answer (score 0):

Change your if 
Why u need to save state? Use state of input.

```
if (eye_button_checked) {
```

to

```
if (password.type == "text") {
```

Comment: Or put your     eye_button_checked = true; out of function